# getJSON returns null

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

jQuery getJSON function returns null, although, as I can see, everything is correct:

```
$.getJSON("/site/ajax/autocomplete/key", function(data) {
    alert(data); //null
    alert(data.term); //null
});
```

Yii-framework PHP backend:

```
public function actionAutocomplete($key) {
    /*some_code*/
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    return json_encode($autocomplete);
}
```

Which returns valid JSON with structure:

```
[{"url":"/bla/bla","name":"Bla Bla"}]
```

And `print_r` of this json works ok.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where are you calling `actionAutocomplete()`?

Comment: Where do you call `actionAutocomplete` method? are you sure you're calling it somewhere?

Comment: When you say that it retuns valid JSON, you saw it in the browser console?

Comment: Do you `echo` at your backend? You get `empty response` with `return`.

Comment: Its in the controller which handles ajax requests. XHR request returns 200, but empty response.

Comment: So in your controller you're doing a echo of the return function ?

Comment: vard, I print_r(json) and checked it with jsonlint

Comment: Are you using a framework?

Comment: vard, in config of my routes I redirect `/site/ajax/autocomplete/key` to this action, no echo in controller

Comment: Could you call the URL `/site/ajax/autocomplete/key` directly in your browser and see if it returns anything ?

Comment: vard, no, it returns chhtpexception! The problem is with routes, I suppose?

Comment: Ah, try to use `die()` instead of `print_r`.

Comment: `print_r(json_encode($autocomplete));die();` gave me `[object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object]`

Comment: @Bojczuk It's a problem with the routes, are you sure your URL accepts `GET` requests? Because by using `$.getJSON`, behind the scenes it will use the GET request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that `print_r` displays variable information - it's not an `echo`, so not a valid JSON structure (which is probably why it doesn't display anything considering the header you sent). You should do `die($json);` directly, so you just send the json string to your browser.

Comment: Well `echo json_encode($autocomplete);` seems to solve my problem, I can see now the needed data in XHR response. Is it right? I should have echo my json and not return?

Comment: Yes `echo` works too. I just like `die` when I'm treating with JSON because with that I'm sure that I don't sent any information after my JSON string.